# codenameone - how to draw an image with graphics

Tags: codenameone

i need your help very much indeed.
I am new in codenameone and i am trying to implement a basic example like, drawing an image with a graphic. i only find some incomplete example and basic idea about drawing an image and i can not do what i want. I need an example from the scratch

When i run the compiler the image is not drawn. I do not know if i have to do something before with the img variable, if so would u please right the code

```
//this the class i call painel

static Image img;

public void paint(Graphcs g)
{

    try
    {
        img.createImage("fundo.jpg");

        g.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
    }
    cathc(IOException ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems catch is misspelled so I'm guessing that the code isn't copied and pasted.

You are opening an image incorrectly (wrong path and ideally you should have gotten it from the resource file) which should throw an exception. Doing it within the paint loop would be **really** slow to boot.

I suggest going over the developer guide in the website and one or more of the tutorials.